# Finding a perpendicular line analytic geonetry

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

I have given this example: Which of the following lines is perpendicular to the line given by the equation 5x − 3y = 2?

a) Line specified parametrically x = 2 + 5s, y = −1−3s, s∈R.

b) The line given by the equation 3x + 5y = −1

c) The line given by the equation 3x + 5y = 1.

d) Line entered parametrically x = 2 + 3s, y = −1 + 5s, s∈R.

I know that the parametric line is given by means of a perpendicular vector, so the vector perpendicular to the line will be in the form (3, 5) in the general form and (5, -3) in the birch, I would conclude that d will be false, but I do not know how dake to continue. Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Parametric line and perpendicularity vector to the line.

Comment: There's a small problem in your post: a parametric line is given by a *directing*, not  perpendicular, vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line $5x-3y=3$ has slope $5/3$ using form $y=mx+c$ for the line where $m$ is the slope, so perpendicular line should have slope $-3/5$, therefore is of the form $3x+5y=k$ for any constant $k$.

Therefore,

> A,B, C are all perpendicular

Comment: so a, b, c are perpendicular and point c does not affect perpendicularity?

Comment: yes, c only affect where line lies in plane,  doesn't affect the slope.